# Find total possible ways to generate from given string

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a binary string of 0's and 1's. Now I want to select a string of length 3 such that no consecutive characters are same.

**Example:**

```
Input : 01011010

Output: 20
```

**Explanation:** All possible combinations are:

```
[0, 1, 0]:: indices : 0,1,2 :: valid
[0, 1, 1]:: indices : 0,1,3
[0, 1, 1]:: indices : 0,1,4
[0, 1, 0]:: indices : 0,1,5 :: valid
[0, 1, 1]:: indices : 0,1,6
[0, 1, 0]:: indices : 0,1,7 :: valid
[0, 0, 1]:: indices : 0,2,3
[0, 0, 1]:: indices : 0,2,4
[0, 0, 0]:: indices : 0,2,5
[0, 0, 1]:: indices : 0,2,6
[0, 0, 0]:: indices : 0,2,7
[0, 1, 1]:: indices : 0,3,4
[0, 1, 0]:: indices : 0,3,5 :: valid
[0, 1, 1]:: indices : 0,3,6
[0, 1, 0]:: indices : 0,3,7 :: valid
[0, 1, 0]:: indices : 0,4,5 :: valid
[0, 1, 1]:: indices : 0,4,6
[0, 1, 0]:: indices : 0,4,7 :: valid
[0, 0, 1]:: indices : 0,5,6
[0, 0, 0]:: indices : 0,5,7
[0, 1, 0]:: indices : 0,6,7 :: valid

[1, 0, 1]:: indices : 1,2,3 :: valid
[1, 0, 1]:: indices : 1,2,4 :: valid
[1, 0, 0]:: indices : 1,2,5
[1, 0, 1]:: indices : 1,2,6 :: valid
[1, 0, 0]:: indices : 1,2,7
[1, 1, 1]:: indices : 1,3,4
[1, 1, 0]:: indices : 1,3,5
[1, 1, 1]:: indices : 1,3,6
[1, 1, 0]:: indices : 1,3,7
[1, 1, 0]:: indices : 1,4,5
[1, 1, 1]:: indices : 1,4,6
[1, 1, 0]:: indices : 1,4,7
[1, 0, 1]:: indices : 1,5,6 :: valid
[1, 0, 0]:: indices : 1,5,7
[1, 1, 0]:: indices : 1,6,7

[0, 1, 1]:: indices : 2,3,4
[0, 1, 0]:: indices : 2,3,5 :: valid
[0, 1, 1]:: indices : 2,3,6
[0, 1, 0]:: indices : 2,3,7 :: valid
[0, 1, 0]:: indices : 2,4,5 :: valid
[0, 1, 1]:: indices : 2,4,6
[0, 1, 0]:: indices : 2,4,7 :: valid
[0, 0, 1]:: indices : 2,5,6
[0, 0, 0]:: indices : 2,5,7
[0, 1, 0]:: indices : 2,6,7 :: valid

[1, 1, 0]:: indices : 3,4,5
[1, 1, 1]:: indices : 3,4,6
[1, 1, 0]:: indices : 3,4,7
[1, 0, 1]:: indices : 3,5,6 :: valid
[1, 0, 0]:: indices : 3,5,7
[1, 1, 0]:: indices : 3,6,7

[1, 0, 1]:: indices : 4,5,6 :: valid
[1, 0, 0]:: indices : 4,5,7
[1, 1, 0]:: indices : 4,6,7

[0, 1, 0]:: indices : 5,6,7 :: valid
```

Of these only 20 combinations are valid so output is 20.

Here is my program.

```
public static long process(String s) {
    long result = 0;
    int n = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                continue;
            }
            for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
                if (s.charAt(j) != s.charAt(k)) {
                    result++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Constaints:**

```
length of input is 1 to 2*10^5.
```

How to reduce time complexity of this program.

Comment: You seem to be repeating the same checks. Are you familiar with N-grams? Take all **unique** length 3 substrings from the input. Then filter out all substrings with consecutive characters, and count the elements that are left

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I am checking all possible strings, I have mentioned the indices also in my explanation so they are different combinations. My output can contain duplicates also that is why my output for given example is 20. I have updated my explanation part with proper information now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first look at all possible binary strings of length 3 such that no consecutive characters are same:

- `101`
- `010`

With that in mind the problem can be reformulated to:

```
for each 0 in input, find all combinations of 1 on either side, plus
for each 1 in input, find all combinations of 0 on either side
```

For any given `0`, the number of combinations of `1` on either side is equal to the number of `1` to the left *times* the number of  `1` to the right (and vice-versa).

Finally, we can combine these two `for` loops into one by switching between the two cases based on the current character. We should also keep track of the `0` and `1` to the left and right, as we don't want to recalculate them all the time. This leaves me with the following algorithm:

```kotlin
var leftZeroes = 0
var leftOnes = 0
var rightZeroes = input.count { it == '0' }
var rightOnes = input.count { it == '1' }
var output = 0
for (char in input) {
    if (char == '0') {
        output += leftOnes * rightOnes
        leftZeroes++
        rightZeroes--
    } else {
        output += leftZeroes * rightZeroes
        leftOnes++
        rightOnes--
    }
}
return output
```

Time complexity: `O(n)` (`count` and `for` are linear in input size, everything else is constant)

Additional space complexity would be `O(1)`, as only those five integers are stored at any time

Comment: input.count { it == '0' }, can you please explain this line. Also what programming language is this?

Comment: `input.count { it == '0' }` counts all `0` in input, for example it would be 4 in your input. It's kotlin code, but you can read it as pseudo code and translate to whatever language you need.